# Form-Select saving more than 1 value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save two values to the DB (user id and user name) with only one form selection field. Is that even possible? This is what I got so far:

`<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.where(brand: current_user.brand), :id, :name, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>`

That only saves the user_id (from :id) to the DB. How would you extend this to save also the user_name (from :name) to the DB?

`<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, :user_name, User.where(brand: current_user.brand), :id, :name, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>`

does not work.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only need to save the user_id in order to reference all of the other attributes.

I like to use `options_for_select` and pass it a two dimensional array when I'm saving an id. The first value will be what the user sees. The second value will be what I actually save. In this case, I'm guessing that you'd like the user to see a `username` but you'd like to actually save the `user_id`.

That would look something like:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.choices) %>
```

and then in user.rb:

```
def self.choices
  choices = []
  User.find_each { |u| choices << [u.username, u.id] }
  choices
end
```

You don't need to save both values because you can always access any attribute saved on user with the id.

EDIT:

per your comment, you actually don't need a select box at all. Just set them in your orders controller `create action`:

```
 @order.username = current_user.username
 @order.user_id = current_user.id

 if @order.save
   # etc
```

Again, though, you don't really need to save the username if you have the user_id as a foreign key. With a foreign key you'll always be able to take an instance of order and say `order.user.username` and get the appropriate username for that user_id.

Comment: This looks great. The reason why I was trying to do it like the way I tried is that I'm saving `@order.user_id = current_user.id` and `@order.user_name = current_user.name` on create action.

Comment: If you want to do that...you actually don't need a select box at all. I'll make an edit to explain.